# awakeFromNib opposite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a reverse of awakeFromNib, a method called when the nib is closed? I know an application delegates receive a notification the the application will terminate, but was wondering if there was to save some state information on a simple NSObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really, but mostly because it generally doesn't make sense.  By the time an individual object is being deallocated, it is generally too late to do anything meaningful.

For saving state, you would generally want to do so periodically, often triggered by some user action (user just entered a bunch of data.... good time to save, user transitioned to a new part of the app.... save).   Only saving as the app is terminated or as a window is closed (or, in your case, as a particular screen is exited) is a recipe for data loss.

Answer (score 2):

For an `NSObject` instance its `dealloc` routine will get called as the object is going away -- you should have a chance there to save off any state you need to before destroying `self` and `super`.

Comment: That is generally too late as the app is already in the middle of tear-down.